# How to run script from parent directory in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, import, scripting, directory

I'm working on a Flask app and run into issues with trying to run a script within a module where the script is in a different directory. I've tried looking at several solutions here and on other sites and haven't been able to find something that works. I have a project structure like so:

```
dashboard\
  app\
    static\
    templates\
    __init__.py
      jobs.py
  api_fetch.py
  config.py
  run.py
```

Within `jobs.py` I have a function that needs to run `api_fetch.py` but for the life of me, I'm not sure what I need to do to that. I've tried imports with `..`, `sys`, `os` and nothings worked. This seems like it shouldn't be that difficult, but I'm at a loss. So far I've only needed to import modules on the same path which work fine.

Answer (score 0):

in `jobs.py`:

```
from .. import api_fetch
```

then 'outside' `dashboard`:

```
$ python -m dashboard.app.jobs
```

`__init__.py` should be in `dashboard` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can just import from parent package `dashboard`, the file structure should like this:

```
dashboard\  
    |app\  
        |static\  
        |templates\  
        -__init__.py  
        -jobs.py  
    -__init__.py  << don't forget this!
    -api_fetch.py  
    -config.py  
    -run.py
```

Then in jobs.py:

```
from dashboard import api_fench
```

Comment: I added `__init__.py` in dashboard\ do I need to move code from app\__init__.py to it? The one in dashboard\ is empty. I am still getting this error:

`from .. import api_fetch
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Comment: Sorry, I got a mistake, you can just import from parent package (see answer).

Comment: tried making that change and getting `ImportError: No module named dashboard` I must be setting up packages wrong. Not sure.